# Transfer function from OpenEthereum

Tags: solidity

thanks for considering my question.
I wonder is there any playaround to use the transfer function without using the OpenEthereum library in smart contract developing.

Also, if yes, what is the pros and cons of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is Yes. I think you mean OpenZeppelin not OpenEthereum. Basically, OpenZeppelin or any smart contract-based library is just a set of smart contracts.

Therefore, you just need to copy/pull their "transfer" function to your smart contract. Here is a piece of code for you to play around.

```
    function _transfer(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal {
        require(sender != address(0), 'BEP20: transfer from the zero address');
        require(recipient != address(0), 'BEP20: transfer to the zero address');
  
        _balances[sender] = _balances[sender].sub(amount, 'BEP20: transfer amount exceeds balance');
        _balances[recipient] = _balances[recipient].add(amount);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
    }

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) public override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }
```

Then, you can use this transfer in any other functions that you like.

Actually, using OpenZeppelin library helps to make thing in developing smart contract more simple, straight-forward, and intuitive than copy their function to your smart contract. The only cons I can think of not using this library is that you need to use a good IDE for deploying the SC, i.e., Hardhat.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. Just one more question, Is it able to use Remix to import the library.

Comment: Hope it helps you. Yes, you can import that library to Remix by referring to this article https://moralis.io/openzeppelin-in-remix-importing-openzeppelin-contracts-in-remix/. However, you should play around to verify that SC in blockchain scan. I suggest you use hardhat for IDE, also, hardhat has an utility to verify the SC easily.

Comment: Thank you for the info.